# Compress File per file, same name

Tags: powershell

I hope you are all safe in this time of COVID-19.

I'm trying to generate a script that goes to the directory and compresses each file to .zip with the same name as the file, for example:

```
sample.txt -> sample.zip
sample2.txt -> sample2.zip
```

but I'm having difficulties, I'm not that used to powershell, I'm learning and improving this script. In the end it will be a script that deletes files older than X days, compresses files and makes them upload in ftp .. the part of excluding with more than X I've already managed it for days, now I grabbed a little bit on this one.

Last try at moment.

```
param
(
    #Future accept input
    [string] $InputFolder,
    [string] $OutputFolder
)

    #test folder
$InputFolder= "C:\Temp\teste"
$OutputFolder="C:\Temp\teste"

$Name2 = Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter '*.csv'| select Name

Set-Variable SET_SIZE -option Constant -value 1
$i = 0
$zipSet = 0




Get-ChildItem $InputFolder | ForEach-Object { 
    $zipSetName =  ($Name2[1]) + ".zip "
    Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath "$OutputFolder\$zipSetName"
    $i++;
    $Name2++

    if ($i -eq $SET_SIZE) {
        $i = 0;
        $zipSet++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things a bit, and it looks like most of the issues are because in your script example `$Name2` will contain a different set of items than the `Get-ChildItem $InputFolder` will return in the loop (i.e. may have other objects other than `.csv` files).

The best way to deal with things is to use variables with the full file object (i.e. you don't need to use `|select name`). So I get all the CSV file objects right away and store in the variable `$CsvFiles`.

We can additionally use the special variable `$_` inside the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) which represents the current object. We also can use `$_.BaseName` to give us the name without the extension (assuming that's what you want, otherwise use `$_Name` to get a zip with the name like `xyz.csv`).

So a simplified version of the code can be:

```
$InputFolder= "C:\Temp\teste"
$OutputFolder="C:\Temp\teste"

#Get files to process
$CsvFiles = Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter '*.csv'

#loop through all files to zip
$CsvFiles | ForEach-Object { 
    $zipSetName =  $_.BaseName + ".zip"
    Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath "$OutputFolder\$zipSetName"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge, it worked as expected, I will extend more about $ _ variables. will be of great value for the continuation of the complete script = D